# Delete columns that had more than 30% of repeated values or more than 1% of values outside the range defined by the mean +- 2.5 SD in r

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, edit

Maybe it is a basic question on data edition but I didn´t found a similar Q&A in stack overflow.

I have a data frame of ~18 rows x 200 columns.
Here it is a reduced toy example:

`DF <- data.frame(x1=c(0.1,1,0.7,765,0.4,0.3,0.5,3.6,5,11), x2=c(2,2,6,7,6,6,4,2,2,2), x3=c(4,2,3,4,5,4.2,4.6,2.2,2.7,2.8))`

I want to delete all columns with more 30% of repeated values, in this case the columns **x2**. In the toy example should be deleted due to have more than 30% of repeated values (many repeated two and six).

I also want to delete the columns with more than 1% of values outside the range defined by the mean +- 2.5 SD. In the toy example the column **x1** should be removed since the SD `sqrt(var(DF$x1))`= 241.14 and the mean `mean(DF$x1)` = 78.76, therefore the mean + 2.5 SD is = 78.76 + (2.5*241.14) = 681.61, and there in the DF$x1 there is a value higher than this, representing the 10% of values in `DF$x1` (due to only have ten rows in the table)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far I have the proportion of duplicated values for each row. i.e dup_val = apply(DF,2, function(x) sum(duplicated(x))/nrow(DF)), but I didn´t figure out how to delete columns by this condition.

Comment: `I want to delete all columns with more 30% of repeated values`. How do you define a repeated value? Anything which occur more than once ?

Comment: Yes, I want to do a quality control for each "variable" or column, so I am interested in each column separately. Therefore I define a repeated value as a value that occur more than once within each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function which incorporates all the rules you want to use to delete a column.

```
remove_col <- function(x) {
  tab <- table(x)
  sd <- sd(x)
  mn <- mean(x)
  
  !(mean(x %in% names(tab[tab > 1])) > 0.3 || 
      sum(x > mn + 2.5 * sd | x < mn - 2.5 * sd) > 0.01*length(x))
}
```

Use it with `Filter`.

```
Filter(remove_col, DF)

#    x3
#1  4.0
#2  2.0
#3  3.0
#4  4.0
#5  5.0
#6  4.2
#7  4.6
#8  2.2
#9  2.7
#10 2.8
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, I double check your answer and I wonder if it is removing the columns that have more than 1% of values out the range +- 2.5 SD, or it is just removing the column that have a value out the range +- 2.5 SD. What do you think? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It was removing columns which had any value outside the range. Sorry. I correct the answer to include the condition that it will remove the column only if more than 1% of the values are outside range. Can you check now?